# Comparing folders in PowerShell

Tags: powershell

I am using this to compare two folders recursively from PowerShell:

http://blogs.technet.com/b/heyscriptingguy/archive/2011/10/08/easily-compare-two-folders-by-using-powershell.aspx

Using these lines:

```
$fso = Get-ChildItem -Recurse -path C:\test\A
$fsoBU = Get-ChildItem -Recurse -path C:\test\B
Compare-Object -ReferenceObject $fso -DifferenceObject $fsoBU
```

Now I have some folders that should be ignored in folder B (e.g. `.git`). Based on the below answer I have tried:

```
$fso = Get-ChildItem -Recurse -path C:\test\A
$fsoBU = Get-ChildItem -Recurse -path C:\test\B  -Exclude @( "C:\test\B\.git" )
Compare-Object -ReferenceObject $fso -DifferenceObject $fsoBU
```

Indeed all files in .git folder are skipped but everything else pops up as being different:

[image]

I doubled checked the folder compare using Beyond compare and no differences were found.

Answer (score 0):

This should work (if you know what you want to exclude ahead of time):

`$fsoBU = Get-ChildItem -Recurse -path C:\test\B -Exclude @( ".nuget", "bin", "obj" )`

You can use `-Include` and `-Exclude` parameters in the same command, they accept string arrays, so how you build it is up to you, the above is just a simple example (wildcards are supported for both).

Also consider using `-Filter`, it's a string but supports wildcards etc but it's better as the filter is applied before the objects are being retrieved, whereas `-Include` and `-Exclude` are applied after.

Comment: Should work... but doesn't. If you use the `-Exclude` argument the FileInfo object that it collects is referenced by the full path, and not the file name. Do a `$fsoBU[0].PSObject` and look at the `ImmediateBaseObject` listed. Now remove the `-Exclude` and do it again. Without the exclude it just lists the file name, but with exclude it shows the full path.

Comment: That's novel, although if you use `$fso = Get-ChildItem -Recurse -path C:\test\a -Exclude @( "" )` to apply an empty filter it seems to return both the same, so may work for your comparison purposes?  Would that work for your purposes?

Answer (score 0):

You sir are being messed with. You are not alone, it happens to most people that do much work with the combination of Get-ChildItem and the FileSystem Provider. Results are inconsistant, and often times confusing why they change. Such as with your case, adding the `-Exclude` argument changes the output of the command to not just reference files, but to reference their full path. This is frustrating to say the least. My only advise is this: A) When running Get-ChildItem against the FileSystem provider use the `-Filter` argument when possible, and B) Do all other filtering after the results are provided by running those results through a `Where` statement. Using `-Include` and `-Exclude` pulls all results from the FileSystem Provider, and then filters the output anyway, so PowerShell is doing the same work, but using a `Where` statement is both more flexible, and more reliable. Try this:

```
$fso = Get-ChildItem -Recurse -path C:\test\A
$fsoBU = Get-ChildItem -Recurse -path C:\test\B | Where{$_.FullName -notlike "C:\test\B\.git*"}
Compare-Object -ReferenceObject $fso -DifferenceObject $fsoBU
```

I'll bet that this change will yield the results that you wanted.

**More Details:** The above answers your question, but here's what I did to find this out...

Created C:\Temp\Test. Placed File1.csv, File2.csv, and File3.csv in it. Copied the folder, and pasted it creating 'C:\Temp\Test - Copy' with all three files. I then deleted C:\Temp\Test - Copy\File2.csv. I ran these commands:

```
$dir1 = gci c:\temp\test -recurse
$dir2 = gci 'c:\temp\test - copy' -recurse
diff $dir1 -dif $dir2
```

I got the expected result saying `$dir1` has File2.csv while `$dir2` does not. Ok, now to filter out something...

```
$dir1 = gci c:\temp\test -recurse -exclude "file1.csv"
diff $dir1 -dif $dir2
```

What the what?? Here's what it tells me:

```
InputObject            SideIndicator
-----------            -------------
File1.csv              =>
File3.csv              =>
C:\temp\test\File2.csv <=
C:\temp\test\File3.csv <=
```

Now why would it list just the file name for `$dir2` and the full path for `$dir1`? Why did that change? Obviously it changed because I added the `-Exclude` argument, but are the objects actually different? Let's look:

```
PS:\Temp> $dir1[0].psobject

BaseObject          : C:\temp\test\File2.csv
Members             : {System.String PSPath=Microsoft.PowerShell.Core\FileSystem::C:\temp\test\File2.csv, System.String PSParentPath=Microsoft.PowerShell.Core\FileSystem::C:\temp\test, System.String 
                      PSChildName=File2.csv, System.Management.Automation.PSDriveInfo PSDrive=C...}
Properties          : {System.String PSPath=Microsoft.PowerShell.Core\FileSystem::C:\temp\test\File2.csv, System.String PSParentPath=Microsoft.PowerShell.Core\FileSystem::C:\temp\test, System.String 
                      PSChildName=File2.csv, System.Management.Automation.PSDriveInfo PSDrive=C...}
Methods             : {string get_Name(), long get_Length(), string get_DirectoryName(), System.IO.DirectoryInfo get_Directory()...}
ImmediateBaseObject : C:\temp\test\File2.csv
TypeNames           : {System.IO.FileInfo, System.IO.FileSystemInfo, System.MarshalByRefObject, System.Object}

PS C:\Temp> $dir2[0].psobject

BaseObject          : File1.csv
Members             : {System.String PSPath=Microsoft.PowerShell.Core\FileSystem::C:\temp\Test - Copy\File1.csv, System.String PSParentPath=Microsoft.PowerShell.Core\FileSystem::C:\temp\Test - Copy, System.String 
                      PSChildName=File1.csv, System.Management.Automation.PSDriveInfo PSDrive=C...}
Properties          : {System.String PSPath=Microsoft.PowerShell.Core\FileSystem::C:\temp\Test - Copy\File1.csv, System.String PSParentPath=Microsoft.PowerShell.Core\FileSystem::C:\temp\Test - Copy, System.String 
                      PSChildName=File1.csv, System.Management.Automation.PSDriveInfo PSDrive=C...}
Methods             : {string get_Name(), long get_Length(), string get_DirectoryName(), System.IO.DirectoryInfo get_Directory()...}
ImmediateBaseObject : File1.csv
TypeNames           : {System.IO.FileInfo, System.IO.FileSystemInfo, System.MarshalByRefObject, System.Object}
```

Yeah, so the ImmediateBaseObject lists a full path to the results where we used `-Exclude` but not for the other results. To me that says that in order to apply `-Include` or `-Exclude` PowerShell has to reference the full path of the object, but if you don't use that it just references the object in and of itself. How to get around this? Use a `Where` statement to filter the results after they're collected.

This doesn't answer the question of WHY?!?, but it does explain how I got here and hopefully will help you troubleshoot similar issues in the future. Sometimes it's more important to figure out how to just work with what you have then to figure out why it works the way it does.